# How can I use this merge sort code in Prolog?

Tags: sorting, prolog, mergesort

So I have this merge sort code

```
merge(List, List, []).
merge(List, [], List).

merge([MinList1|RestMerged], [MinList1|RestList1], [MinList2|RestList2]) :-
  MinList1 =< MinList2,
  merge(RestMerged,RestList1,[MinList2|RestList2]).
merge([MinList2|RestMerged], [MinList1|RestList1], [MinList2|RestList2]) :-
  MinList2 =< MinList1,
  merge(RestMerged,[MinList1|RestList1],RestList2).

mergeSort([], []).
mergeSort([A], [A|[]]).

mergeSort(Sorted, List) :-
    length(List, N),
    FirstLength is //(N, 2),
    SecondLength is N - FirstLength,
    length(FirstUnsorted, FirstLength),
    length(SecondUnsorted, SecondLength),
    append(FirstUnsorted, SecondUnsorted, List),
    mergeSort(FirstSorted, FirstUnsorted),
    mergeSort(SecondSorted, SecondUnsorted),
    merge(Sorted, FirstSorted, SecondSorted).
```

but instead of doing

**mergeSort(S, [9,8,7,6,5]).**

on prolog, how can I use it by asking the user how many numbers to input and then proceed to input numbers that will be sorted.

For example:

Number of items? **5**
*here the user will input 5 numbers to be sorted*
**9.**
**8.**
**7.**
**6.**
**5.**

and the final answer will be

**S=[5,6,7,8,9].**

Comment: Sorry had written a wrong hint (deleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** The `start` predicate ask the user to enter how many digits he/she would want to enter. The number entered will act as a `counter`.

**2-** The `m` predicate will run that amount of number of times our counter has been specified. The value of Number will be pushed into the List.

**3-** The counter keeps decreasing till it reaches `zero`. By now we have a list with our numbers.

**4-** Next pass the List to `mergeSort` to give the final sorted List. Which is displayed using write.

```
merge(List, List, []).
merge(List, [], List).

merge([MinList1|RestMerged], [MinList1|RestList1], [MinList2|RestList2]) :-
  MinList1 =< MinList2,
  merge(RestMerged,RestList1,[MinList2|RestList2]).
merge([MinList2|RestMerged], [MinList1|RestList1], [MinList2|RestList2]) :-
  MinList2 =< MinList1,
  merge(RestMerged,[MinList1|RestList1],RestList2).

mergeSort([], []).
mergeSort([A], [A|[]]).

mergeSort(Sorted, List) :-
    length(List, N),
    FirstLength is //(N, 2),
    SecondLength is N - FirstLength,
    length(FirstUnsorted, FirstLength),
    length(SecondUnsorted, SecondLength),
    append(FirstUnsorted, SecondUnsorted, List),
    mergeSort(FirstSorted, FirstUnsorted),
    mergeSort(SecondSorted, SecondUnsorted),
    merge(Sorted, FirstSorted, SecondSorted).

start:-
    write('Select total digits to enter:'),
    read(Counter),
    m(L,Counter),
    mergeSort(LS,L),
    write(LS),!.

m([],0):-!.
m([Number|List],Counter):-
    write('Enter Number'),
    read(Number),
    Counter1 is Counter-1,
    m(List,Counter1).
```

**Example:**

```
?- start.

Select total digits to enter:
5
Enter Number
55
Enter Number
6
Enter Number
22
Enter Number
8
Enter Number
99
[6, 8, 22, 55, 99]
1true
```

Comment: Have a look at the query ` m([X|Xs],0).` - it doesn't terminate but it should actually fail. If you fix the source for that, you will not need the cut in the base case for `m/2` anymore.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `m([]). m([X|Xs]) :- read(X), m(Xs). m(Xs,L) :- length(Xs,L), m(Xs).`. Similar to the `mergeSort` code you first make sure that `Xs` is a list of the correct size and then the list itself serves as counter for the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use read (it expects a term and needs to end with a dot):

```
?- read(Xs), mergeSort(S, Xs).
|: [1,3,2,4,5].

Xs = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5],
S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] .
```

Comment: Also, if using swi-prolog then write read(Xs), mergeSort(S, Xs),!. with a cut(!), or it just keep on repeating the answer.

Comment: That is an issue of the sorting algorithm and should be properly addressed there. It will only repeat a finite number of times though.